# Transfer large files (Server/Client) with .NET

Tags: .net, wcf, tcp

I want to download and upload some large files to a server.

But i dont know what is better to use

- TCP/IP (with the System.Net.Sockets class)
- WCF Service (without IIS - i use the the ServiceHost class)

or something else?

Comment: Personally, I'd just chunk it... instead of trying to send 1 big message, send multiple smaller messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write more about the context. If you need authentication you may consider WCF. With WCF there's a **very little** overhead but you manage security/authentication/changes easily. The raw file transfer (using the same channel) shouldn't be different with WCF so the added complexity must be considered if you need its features.

Moreover if you have to transfer a large amount of data you should consider that connection may fail so you should manage this situation, I guess you don't want to force your users to upload/download from the beginning. You may consider to use a well-known protocol for this such as FTP (supported by WCF) or available in the `FtpWebRequest` class.

Good article for comparison of different technologies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx (but please note you have one single big data transfer, not multiple small transfers).

Comment: "very little overhead" - I lol'd... WCF is *not* a delicate flower - it very much can have quite a noticeable overhead

Comment: LOL I was _half_ ironic, WCF isn't light but it depends on the channel stack (I guess with wrong choices you can get 50% performance). With large files, if well configured, it may be not so noticeable. In this case I think its biggest issue is latency.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use System.Net.FtpWebRequest.

This was intended for exactly this purpose.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx